# Unable to download artifacts in external organisation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, artifacts, azure-artifacts

I want to download artifacts published as pipeline artifacts in an external organization. I linked them as artifacts in the classic release pipeline and facing the following:

[image: logs]

I was able to download the same 'when they are published using 'Publish Build Artifacts' task. But when 'Publish Pipeline artifacts task is used to publish, I was not able to download and the error thrown was 'Unsupported Artifact type: Pipeline artifact'.

As 'Publish Build Artifacts' is going to be deprecated, Why is this feature not available in 'Publish Pipeline artifacts' task. Is there any other to download external organization artifacts?

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other to download external organization artifacts?

Do you use `Download Artifacts-External Build` task (Install [TFS artifacts for Release Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-externaltfs&targetId=3a41ecc8-c588-4c54-ae94-8a8231f3bdf1&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) extension from the marketplace)? If not, you can try it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried the same but the artifacts are downloaded only when they are published by Publish build artifacts task and not Publish pipeline artifacts task. Publish build artifacts task is going to be deprecated soon. Hence, we are not using it. Also the filter here doesn't work properly. It tries to download all artifacts and match the pattern. This is causing the pipeline to fail when access to some artifacts published as file share is not available.